# Does AGM preserve Google Map's session when component is re-initialised?

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, agm

We're currently working on a map-load heavy portal for sales in Angular. We decided to use the [AGM library](https://angular-maps.com/) which provided a very good support for both Angular and TypeScript.

We display the map on **every Search results page** and when the user is navigating back-and-forth from Search results to Product's detail page we destroy/re-initialise the `MapComponent`. I'm a bit worried if this will not trigger additional Google Maps requests/sessions as it's re-initialised, but I have no idea how to do the metrics. We, unfortunately, cannot easily hide/show the component because of our app's architecture.

So the question is how the session behaves in the AGM? Does each re-initialisation of the component create a new paid request? Thank you in advance.

Comment: remove angular-google-maps tag, as it currently points to obsolete angularjs component library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As any other angular component, when `agm-map` is removed from the component tree, it's removed from the DOM. The `google.maps.Map` object is destroyed, and recreated when the component is shown again.

The reinitalization is not completely from scratch, though. google maps script is loaded only once per project (at least once per calling `AgmCoreModule.forRoot` which *should* be called only once in any normal project). So while `google.maps.Map object` is destroyed and reinitialized, the script remains.

Your last location and all polygons, etc WILL NOT be cached, because when an `agm-map` component is created or recreated, it sets the center attribute from scratch.

As for prices, [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing#dynamic-maps) seems to suggest that you ***will*** be charged for every recreation of the map.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and detailed information.